# leaflet for R issues with shape file

Tags: r, leaflet, shapes

I try to make a map with the leaflet package on Rstudio.
I try many examples and self options and they all work properly.

But I would like to use a shape file I have at work.
It work with all the software (QGIS, R *spplot* etc.) but when I use the shape file in leaflet it dosen't work, a blue line appear on the top of the map.

Here is the code i use :

> ```
> dat<-readOGR(dsn="shape/Shape ER 2015", layer=filename,encoding='UTF-8')
> leaflet(dat)%>%addTiles()%>%
> addPolgons(data=dat, weight=2)
> ```

Here is the result with the code :

[image: bad map]

and here is the map obtained with spplot :

```
spplot(dat, zcol=1, col.regions="gray", col="blue")
```

[image]

I have used the same file with http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/ to see if the issue come from my data. But it appear that it come from `readOGR`

I put here some informations of the `SpatialPolygonDataframe`

```
  str(dat@polygons[[1]],2)
```

> ```
> Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
>   ..@ Polygons :List of 1
>   ..@ plotOrder: int 1
>   ..@ labpt    : num [1:2] 953652 6808716
>   ..@ ID       : chr "0"
>   ..@ area     : num 4.32e+10
> ```

```
 str(dat@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]],2)
```

> ```
> Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
>   ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] 953652 6808716
>   ..@ area   : num 4.32e+10
>   ..@ hole   : logi FALSE
>   ..@ ringDir: int 1
>   ..@ coords : num [1:1063, 1:2] 940343 939824 936328 933274 933649 ...
> ```

```
 head(dat@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)
```

> ```
>        [,1]    [,2]
> [1,] 940343 6611180
> [2,] 939824 6610705
> [3,] 936328 6613788
> [4,] 933274 6616467
> [5,] 933649 6617058
> [6,] 934305 6617147
> ```

Hope it's clear, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely need to transform your projection.
Try:

```
PRO <- sp::CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0')
DAT <- sp::spTransform(dat,PRO)
```

Comment: Your're my hero !
Can you explain me the idea ? How it works ?

Comment: Leaflet's default projection is EPSG:3857, also known as "Google Mercator" or "Web Mercator"